# how to read number of users number from data. Properties file in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I Want to create test that gets every time (in a loop) different customer number and make some operations on him and after that take the 2nd customer number and etc.
Therefore I create data.properties file containing the next data :

```
customernumber1=500054237
customernumber2=500054238
customernumber3=500054235
```

I decelerate the variable

```
customernumber = getObject("customernumber");
```

my getObject method

```
public static String getObject(String Data) throws IOException
    
    {
        loadData();
        String data = properties.getProperty(Data); 
        return data;
        
    }
```

I have this code :

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3 ; i++ )
            {

            bo.textfield().sendKeys("customers");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.customers().click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.opencustomers().click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.customerid().sendKeys(customernumber + i);
```

But the result of this is a : "null1", in the 1st run.

How can I call every time the customer number I have in the properties file ?
I think I need to call the property name and not the property value - is this is true ? and if so how can I make it ?
Thanks.

Comment: please share your `getObject` method code

Comment: The getObject method works fine, I use it with many more classes.

Comment: Please Prophet I add it

Comment: I see that `customernumber + i` is actually giving you `null1`. That means `customernumber = getObject("customernumber"); ` is making `customernumber ` = `null`. maybe you are passing a wrong file path etc here?

Comment: No - the path is OK - the null as I understand is output saying the parameter customernumber is something the system doesn't recognize as I trying to pass : customernumber1=500054237

Comment: Right. We need to debug this. With the information I currently have here I don't see how can I help. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
The main culprit here is that you are passing "customernumber" in the getObject method, which doesn't exist in the property file.

```
 customernumber = getObject("customernumber");
```

You can see there is no such thing as "customernumber"

```
//Actual Property file data:
        customernumber1=500054237
        customernumber2=500054238
        customernumber3=500054235
```

Also, you are passing (customernumber + i), which has not much effect, as it will only add null1, null2 or so on, as per your current code. `bo.customerid().sendKeys(customernumber + i);`

One more thing, the loop should be i<=3 instead of i<3

---

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3 ; i++ )
            {

            bo.textfield().sendKeys("customers");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.customers().click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.opencustomers().click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bo.customerid().sendKeys(customernumber + i);
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Solution:**

Inside your for loop, plz initilize your String customernumber = getObject("customernumber"+i); and pass "i" dynamic variable to get dynamic data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++ ) {
        String customernumber = getObject("customernumber"+i);
        System.out.println(customernumber);
        bo.textfield().sendKeys("customers");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        bo.customers().click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        bo.opencustomers().click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        bo.customerid().sendKeys(customernumber);
    }
}



public static String getObject(String Data) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(Data);
    Properties properties =  loadData();
    String data = properties.getProperty(Data);
    return data;

}


public static Properties loadData() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fn = new FileInputStream(new File("{YOUR-PATH}"));
    prop.load(fn);

    return prop;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

---

**Best Approach**: is to use Dataprovider with exce and to pass the data to Dataproviders by reading the data from excel sheet. DataProvider helps to send multiple sets of data to a test method

Ref: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/import-data-from-excel-and-pass-to-data-provider